Using tbl_summary() to create pooled Table 1 after MICE imputation
I used MICE to impute on missingness in my data but do not know if it is possible to use tbl_summary() to create a pooled descriptive table.
I am not sure how to approach this problem or if it is feasible with tbl_summary().

This is not supported, unfortunately. But, we're currently making some changes that would make this type of summary possible. While I am not looking to make this available myself, it could be extended by anyone after the update (expected summary 2024)
